# From 6 different fields update or insert values into database

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and Mysql How would you allow users to update or insert information about themselves from six fields. E.g.  about, name, website  and more? . Would you first use a loop to find all the fields which the user wants to update  then query the database  with insert or update statements  depending if the field is null or an exsisting value has to be overridden.

## Example

```
$Name ; //exsisting value
$email; // existing value
$about;  //fields null
$website;  // user wants to update this field


protected function updateWebsiteinformation($website,$updateArray){

          $this->setTable('userinformation'); //sets Table
          $where = "website = $website";  //where statment
          return $this->update($updateArray, $where); returns statement
```

Comment: If they want to update information, I would present the current information to the user first. Then I would update all fields as submitted by their update request. If you want to restrict the fields to update, you still offer all the data and only the mutable fields as input fields. It is all up to your choices.

Answer (score 2):

there's something funny about your "where" statement. You should have use unique table field instead of field that your users want to update. And for updating process, i would rather update all field at once.